# allow only three news items

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a news feed and am trying to allow three news updates (per person) at a time.

The structure of the MYSQL db is as follows:

```
username|update1|update2|update3

bill     foo     bar     baz
```

I am wondering how I can make it so that when bill posts a new news update:

- the value of `update3` would be removed
- the value from `update2`  would be moved to `update3`
- the value from `update1` would be moved to `update2`
- and the new news update would be placed at `update1`

Would this be possible in simply a MYSQL query or would I have to use PHP to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table
    SET update3 = update2,
        update2 = update1,
        update1 = {$your_input} 
    WHERE your_filter = your_condition
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Completely forgot you can set multiple items at once!

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround:  A possible disadvantage to such a system is that there is no way to find out what would have been shown in the past.  Furthermore, in the case of a system glitch (like if Marco's query were triggered accidentally or maliciously) it would wipe out the updates.

Comment: @wallyk You are right, starting to think better of your answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of denormalizing the data like that, keep it pure:

```
timestamp|username|update
```

Then the last three updates can always be obtained with

```
select *
from updates
where username = 'the user'
order by timestamp descending
limit 3
```